# Calculating product of 3 numbers modulo m

Tags: algorithm, math

Given integers a,b,c and m, I need to calculate `(a*b*c)%m`, where a,b,c and m can be as large as 10^18. I know how to calculate (a*b)%m as follows:

```
unsigned long long mulmod(unsigned long long a,unsigned long long b,unsigned long long c){
unsigned long long x = 0,y=a%c;
while(b > 0){
    if(b%2 == 1) {
        x = (x+y)%c;
    }
    y = (y*2)%c;
    b /= 2;
}
return x%c;
```

}

Can something like this be done for `(a*b*c)%m`?

Answer (score 3):

Let assume that your function `mulmod(a, b, m)` works where it returns the reminder of `(a * b) / m`. You can compute `(a * b * c) % m` by `mulmod(mulmod(a, b, m), c, m)`

You might why does it work? Why does `(a * b * c) % m` is equal to `((a * b) % m) * c % m`. You can prove as the following:

Let

```
Let          a * b = dm + r
             c     = em + q
Therefore,   a * b * c = (dm + r) * (em + q)
                       = (dem + dq + er)m + rq

So           (a * b * c) % m = [(de + r + q)m + rq] % m 
                             = rq % m

How about    [(a * b) % m] * c % m
We know that (a * b) % m = r
Therefore    [(a * b) % m] * c % m = [r * (em + q)] % m
                                   = (rem + rq) % m
                                   = rq % m

Hence, [(a * b) % m] * c % m and (a * b * c) % m are the same
```

Comment: @invisial Will it be equal.?How can u say that?

Comment: @user3086701, I have added the explanation.

Comment: @invisal When you moved to line 3 `= (de + r + q)m + rq`  I think it should be `= (dem + dq + er)m + rq` am I right?

Comment: @Gaith, you are right because I didn't really pay much attention on it since everything inside (...) * *m* will be useless. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 1):

The multiplication property for modular arithmetic is as follows:

```
ab mod m = (a mod m)(b mod m) mod m                          // Rule 1
```

From this it follows that:

```
abc mod m = (ab mod m)(c mod m) mod m                       // Expand (ab)c mod m
          = ((a mod m)(b mod m) mod m mod m)(c mod m) mod m // Expand ab mod m
          = ((a mod m)(b mod m) mod m)(c mod m) mod m       // Trim extra mod m
          = (a mod m)(b mod m)(c mod m) mod m               // Reverse rule 1 with
                                                            // a' = (a mod m)(b mod m)
                                                            // b' = c mod m
```

This suggests two options for implementing three-way modular multiplication. The simplest is to multiply all three mod m terms, and mod m the result, but you're less likely to experience overflow if you mod m each intermediate result. Assuming C++:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
T mulmod(T (&multiplicands)[N], T m) {
    T result = 1;
    for (T n : multiplicands)
        result = (result * (n % m)) % m;
    return result;
}

int nums = {123, 345, 656, 841};
std::cout << mulmod(nums, 373) << "\n"; // Prints 88
```